# The armature just stopped working

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

I made three bones for a roof so i can move it. simple. I did automatic weight. worked perfect as i wanted. but the next day they just stopped working. I was in pose, not reset mode, tried to move it. Nothing. its like i never made them have automatic  weights. so I put automatic weights again. nothing. I have no separate parts. Please help?

Comment: Please, add screenshots or upload a file

Comment: Our guessing powers are quite limited. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.